# VS not responding when I click "choose items"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-ajax, toolbox

I have a problem where when I click on the toolbox, then click "choose items" VS begins to not respond and then closes.

I'm trying to add AJAX Control Toolkit but can't because VS has a fit each time I click to add the items.

Does anybody know why or how to solve it?

I am running on a website instead of an application, does this matter?

Comment: Try running VS with logging enabled (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx). This will generate an xml log file that could provide you with more info about what is causing the crash.

Comment: Thanks but how do you do this?

Comment: Click *Start - All Programs - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Visual Studio Tools - Visual Studio Command Prompt*. Then type *devenv /log* and press *enter*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting Visual Studio 2010 with devenv / safe mode.